# Vary Tag For Dynamic Serving Mobile Pages

Tags: html, mobile, meta-tags, googlebot-mobile

You know; Google suggest us to use Vary Tag at our diynamic content mobile pages.

please check the link: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/configurations/dynamic-serving

I couldnt understand how to use this tag. Do you have any idea where will i put it?

and how will we calculate Content-Length?

and how to customize this part 'GET /page-1 HTTP/1.1'?

is this a meta-tag(<>)? or just copy paste these lines to all our mobile pages?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Vary: User-Agent
Content-Length: 5710
```

Could you give an example of usage this Vary Code; in example.php for example.. where wil i put it; before  tag; instead of  tag?

`<html>
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Content-Type: text/html
    Vary: User-Agent
    Content-Length: 5710
<body>
</body>
</html>` etc..

Comment: This is server response header stuff and not HTML stuff. The page you linked to was terrible. Here are some links: http://searchengineland.com/mobile-site-configuration-the-varies-header-for-enterprise-seo-163004 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975416/what-is-the-function-of-the-vary-accept-http-header and http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.44 There is little out there on this. Essentially, (if I read things right) the vary tag (not HTML) is for sites that are mobile only and is a setting within the web server itself.

Comment: is that mean, i dont need to do anyting? (if its auto creating by server.. my site has diynamic content mobile version )

Comment: I don't know if you do or not. It depends upon your environment. If you are using responsive design, then "No." You do not have to make this change. If you have a mobile site, then it is an option to study whether you make a change to your mobile site configuration or not. It appears to be primarily for caching. If you are worried about whether or not to make this change, I would say do not worry about it today but study it. It is a technical study that will take time to understand. Perhaps someone will have a good answer for you.

Comment: thank you so much closetnoc.. i'm going to wait; as you said too 'its not a urgent problem' (my site is changing its view by php; i mean, its neither responsive nor mobile site; it calls dynamic content)

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is setting a header value for *Vary*.

The following PHP example will add a header value for:

*Vary: Mozilla/1.22 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; PalmOS 3.0) EudoraWeb 2*

```
<?php
$httpRequest->setHeaders(array('Vary' => 'Mozilla/1.22 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; PalmOS 3.0) EudoraWeb 2'));
?>
```

You will want to use PHP's `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];` to detect the user-agent.